# Ajax event dosn't work in <p:calendar> component PrimeFaces

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have two `<p:calendar>` components with the  `timeOnly='true'` property in my xhtml page and I need to validate the components. If I choose the first time as 9:00 am the second component need to be grather (10:00am) so I use an `<p:ajax>` that update the second component, but I don't really know why the event didn't work, I tried using `dateSelec`, `blur` and `change`and only works with `blur` but not the first time and not how I need.

This is my xhtml

```
 <p:dialog id="dlNuevo" widgetVar="agregarOferta" header="Nueva oferta" modal="true" resizable="false" appendTo="@(body)" closable="false">
        <h:form id="nuevoHorarioForm">
            <p:outputPanel id="nuevoPanel">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="nuevoGrid">
                <h:outputLabel value="Hora inicio" for="calendarInicio"/>
                <p:calendar id="calendarInicio" widgetVar="horaInicioSpin" value="#{hbean.horaInicial}" timeOnly="true" pattern="HH:mm a">

                    <p:ajax process="@this" event="blur" update="finCal"/>
                </p:calendar>

                <h:outputLabel value="Hora final" for="finCal"/>
                <p:calendar id="finCal" widgetVar="calendarFin" value="#{hbean.horaFinal}" minHour="#{hbean.horaInicial.hours}" 
                            timeOnly="true" pattern="HH:mm a"/>

                <h:outputLabel value="Días"/>    
                <p:selectManyCheckbox layout="pageDirection" value="#{hbean.diasLista}" >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{hbean.enumeradorDias}" var="dias" itemLabel="#{dias.getLongName( facesContext.viewRoot.locale )}"/>
                </p:selectManyCheckbox>

                <p:commandButton value="Guardar" actionListener="#{hbean.guardarHora(hbean.horaInicial, hbean.horaFinal)}" oncomplete="PF('agregarOferta').hide()" 
                                 update=":formTable:ofertasTBL nuevoHorarioForm :mensajesOfertas"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" onclick="PF('agregarOferta').hide()">

                </p:commandButton>   
            </h:panelGrid>
            </p:outputPanel>                
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

this is my bean

```
 @ManagedBean(name = "hbean")

    @ViewScoped

    public class

    HorariosOfertasBean extends SICEAbstractBean {
    private List<HorariosOfertados> horariosOferta;
    private HorariosOfertados horarioSeleccionado;
    private HorariosOfertados horarioItem;
    private Date horaFinal;
    private Date horaInicial;
    private Days[] diasLista;
    FacesMessage message = null;
    FacesContext currentInstance;
    FacesResourceUtil facesResouces;

    public Days[] getDiasLista() {
        return diasLista;
    }

    public void setDiasLista(Days[] diasLista) {
        this.diasLista = diasLista;
    }

    public List<HorariosOfertados> getHorariosOferta() {
        return horariosOferta;
    }

    public void setHorariosOferta(List<HorariosOfertados> horariosOferta) {
        this.horariosOferta = horariosOferta;
    }

    public Date getHoraFinal() {
        return horaFinal;
    }

    public void setHoraFinal(Date horaFinal) {
        this.horaFinal = horaFinal;
    }

    public Date getHoraInicial() {
        return horaInicial;
    }

    public void setHoraInicial(Date horaInicial) {
        this.horaInicial = horaInicial;
    }

    public HorariosOfertados getHorarioSeleccionado() {
        return horarioSeleccionado;
    }

    public void setHorarioSeleccionado(HorariosOfertados horarioSeleccionado) {
        this.horarioSeleccionado = horarioSeleccionado;
    }

    public HorariosOfertados getHorarioItem() {        
        return horarioItem;
    }

    public void setHorarioItem(HorariosOfertados horarioItem) {
        this.horarioItem = horarioItem;
    }

    public Days[] getEnumeradorDias() {
        return Days.values();
    }

    public void convertTime(XMLGregorianCalendar principio, XMLGregorianCalendar ultimo){                
        horaInicial = principio.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();        
        horaFinal = ultimo.toGregorianCalendar().getTime(); 
    }

    public void convertDays(ListaDiasType valor){
        if(valor != null && valor.getDias() != null){
            diasLista = new Days[valor.getDias().size()];
            for(int i=0;i<valor.getDias().size();i++){
                diasLista[i] = Days.valueOf(valor.getDias().get(i).intValue());
      }      
        }
    }

    public void editarForm(){
        convertTime(getHorarioSeleccionado().getHoraInicio(), getHorarioSeleccionado().getHoraFin());
        convertDays(getHorarioSeleccionado().getDias());
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        facesResouces = new FacesResourceUtil("mx.edu.uteq.sice.core.resources.OfertasMessages", false); 
        horarioSeleccionado = new HorariosOfertados();
        horarioItem = new HorariosOfertados();
        setHorariosOferta(getService().getCommonWebServicePort().getHorariosOfertados());
    }
public void guardarHora(Date hInicio, Date hFin) throws DatatypeConfigurationException, EntityConstraintException_Exception, EntitySQLException_Exception {
        Organizaciones org = new Organizaciones();
        Short org2 = 2;

        org.setIdOrganizacion(org2);
        horarioItem.setIdOrganizacion(org);

        GregorianCalendar gcini = new GregorianCalendar();
        gcini.setTime(hInicio);
        GregorianCalendar gcfin = new GregorianCalendar();
        gcfin.setTime(hFin);

        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlInicio = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gcini);
        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlFin = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gcfin);

        ListaDiasType listaDiasType = new ListaDiasType();
        for (Days diasLista1 : diasLista) {
            listaDiasType.getDias().add(BigDecimal.valueOf(Days.valueOf(diasLista1.name()).getDayOfWeekValue()));
        }
        horarioItem.setDias(listaDiasType);
        horarioItem.setHoraInicio(xmlInicio);
        horarioItem.setHoraFin(xmlFin);
        horarioItem = getService().getCommonWebServicePort().insertHorariosOferta(getHorarioItem());
        getHorariosOferta().add(horarioItem);
        message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, facesResouces.getString("offerSchedule.add"), "Operación Exitosa");
        currentInstance = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        currentInstance.addMessage(null, message);

        setHorarioItem(new HorariosOfertados());
    }
```

This is what the component do.
[image]

I really need help to undestand why this happend. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried 'dateSelect' and doesn't work, it works with 'blur' but only the second time I click the second 'calendar'. Some one told me that I need to use **jQuery** and I'm searching how to do it..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use change event in `pf:calender`, you have to use `f:ajax` on the place of `pf:ajax`. And if you are using `pf:ajax` `dateSelect` event then are you using `DateSelectEvent` in your listener method.

`public void myMethod(DateSelectEvent event)`

Comment: No, i don't have that in my listener, could you explain me why i need it, I'm really new in PrimeFaces... Thanks

Comment: If you mention it as input parameter it want accepr your event to work on from ui. Give it a try.

Comment: It's strange because I probe it once and didn't work but if a click the cancel button instead of Save and tried again it works fine.

Comment: I can't find Your submit button's listener on bean class, is it in your abstract class?

Comment: I updated the question and I added the method for actionListener.

Comment: I think it's happening becauae you have kept your dialogu outside of your form.